# How to update a notification badge on tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, notifications, badge

I have two tabs and when click elements (portlet div) on Master tab, badge will increase, also when click on Creation tab, badge will return to 0.

Two tabs look like these:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#master">Master</a></li>
   <li><a href="#creation">Add List 
      <span id="newExam" class="badge" 
         style="background-color: lightgreen; border-color: green">0</span> 
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#master").click(function(){
    //Implementation to increase Badge size.
});

$("#creation").click(function(){
    $("#newExam").text("0");
});
```